# Can I input to a table without a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using the Devise-multi-email gem to allow the use of multiple emails associated to 1 account.

My issue: I am looking to create multiple emails to associate with 1 account but not sure if a controller is needed or how I can go about this without one in order to input the the table and associate it with a user.

Question: How can I input into the table without a controller, and only a model, is it possible? or should i be doing this differently?

This is probably rudimentary but I want to make sure I am going about solving this the right way.

gem: https://github.com/allenwq/devise-multi_email

I put the gem into my app, created the email model:

```
belong_to :user
```

It correctly associates with the user id and has a primary boolean

and user model:

```
has_many :emails

devise :multi_email_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
```

I create a new account, the account saves, email saves into emails tables and associates with the users table correctly, etc.

Now I want to allow the user to add email and I want to make sure I'm doing this right.

Should i be creating a controller for email - or is there a way to input the multi emails without a controller?

Should i be nesting emails under users, creating a controller, etc.?

Again, sorry if this is a no brainer type of question, but i haven't found any documentation on this aside from the gem.  I know the gem probably assumes i know what i am doing, but i don't and want to make sure I am going about this the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take the emails as parameters for the `users#update` action in your `UsersController`

Simply add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails` to your user model and you can updated them via `{ user: { id: 1, email_attributes: [{ email: 'alice@example.com }, { email: 'alice@work.com'}] } }`

For more information on nested attributes check out the docs here https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Also here is an example on how to add many tasks to a user using this method https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/